# How to connect to contract via javascript deployed using truffle

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-invocation, truffle-contract

I have deployed a contract using truffle on the testrpc network. I need to write a Javascript code that can connect to the contract and run the functions of the contract but I can't figure out how to do that.

Edit:

I am now using `truffle-contract` and `truffle-artifactor` in order to connect to deployed contracts. Here is the artifactor code :

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var fs = require("fs");
var Artifactor = require("truffle-artifactor");
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
var contract = require("truffle-contract");
var temp = require("temp").track();
var path = require("path");
var requireNoCache = require("require-nocache")(module);


var abiVal = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/DINRegistry.json'))

var contractData = {
    contract_name: "DINRegistry",
    abi: abiVal
}

var dirPath = temp.mkdirSync({
    dir: path.resolve("./"),
});

var my_path = '/home/lee/Music/DIN-master';
var expected_filepath = path.join(my_path, '/build/contracts/DINRegistry.json')

function artifactCreator() {
    const artifactor = new Artifactor(my_path);

    artifactor.save({
        contract_name: "DINRegistry",
        abi: abiVal
    }, "./DINRegistry.sol.js")
}

artifactCreator();
```

The code isn't able to create the file `DINRegistry.sol.js`. What is incorrect in this code?

Comment: Please read the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

We had this same requirement in one of the project where we interacted with truffle deployed contract from JavaScript. You can check this script for reference - https://github.com/Imaginea/lms/blob/master/server/routes.js

Basically, we are doing following things -

- define truffle artifacts
- define web3 http provider, set provider
- create contract instance with the help of deployed address.

Hope this helps.